# what is the variance of a constant matrix times a random vector?

Tags: variance, random-matrices, linear-regression

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$In this [video](https://youtu.be/4oanu3D3q6o) is claimed that if the equation of errors in OLS is given by:
$$u=y - X\beta$$
Then in the presence of heteroscedasticity the variance of $u$, will not be constant, $\sigma^2 \times I$, where $I$ is an identity matrix, but:
$$\Var(u\mid X)=\sigma^2\Omega$$
In order to account for the heteroskedasticity, we can estimate the transform system, such that $P$ is a transformation matrix.
$$Py=PX\beta-Pu$$
Where "the variance of a constant matrix $P$ times a random vector $u$" is:
$$\Var(Pu\mid X)=P\Var(u\mid X)P'=P(\sigma^2\Omega)P'$$
Can somebody explain me the proof for that?

Comment: You are right, I don't understand why the variance of a constant matrix P, times a random vector u, is Var(Pu)=PuP' why?

Comment: I believe you do not have any problems with first three equations but variance of a linear transform. $$Var(P u) = E[(P(u-u_{mu}))^2] $$ $$Var(P u) = E[(P(u-u_{mu}))(P(u-u_{mu}))^{H}]= E[P(u-u_{mu})(u-u_{mu})^{H} P^{H}]=PE[(u-u_{mu})(u-u_{mu})^{H}] P^{H}=PVar(u)P^{H}$$

Comment: You can replace $u$ with $u$|$X$ as they both are random variables and I used $u$ as a dummy variable above. So Var(Pu)=PVar(u)P' with your notation

Comment: Great!, in this case, 'H', is the transpose, right?

Comment: Yes transpose for real signals/vectors and Hermitian for complex ones. and $u_mu$ is the expectation of $u$

Comment: You are great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

$$
\operatorname{var}(AX) = A\Big( \operatorname{var}(X) \Big) A^T.
$$

- $X\in\mathbb R^{\ell\times1}$ is a random column vector,
- $\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{E}((X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T)$, where $\mu=\operatorname{E}(X),$ is an $\ell\times\ell$ constant (i.e. non-random) matrix,
- $A\in\mathbb R^{k\times\ell}$ is a constant matrix,
- and so $\operatorname{var}(AX)\in\mathbb R^{k\times k}$ is a constant matrix.

The proof is this:
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{var}(AX) \\[10pt]
= {} &  \operatorname{E}\Big((A(X-\mu))(A(X-\mu))^T\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \operatorname{E}\Big(A(X-\mu)(X-\mu))^T A^T\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & A \operatorname{E}\Big((X-\mu)(X-\mu))^T \Big) A^T \\[10pt]
= {} & A \Big( \operatorname{var}(X) \Big) A^T.
\end{align}

Comment: This is very similar to what keoxkeox posted before. TX